# How to transfer a file from my downloads folder to my media folder? (Nexus 4)

Tags: nexus-4, downloading, ringtone

I have downloaded an mp3 I want to use as a ringtone. I don't want to connect my phone (Nexus 4) to my computer, I just want to transfer the file from my downloads folder to the appropriate folder where it can be used as a ringtone. I'd rather not download an app for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use a root browser like ES Explorer or even easier is to add a folder on SD denoting what you wish to use it for ie. Ringtone, alarm, ui, notification

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder named 'Ringtones' to your SD card.  Add your ringtone files to that folder.

In the same manner add folders named 'Notifications', 'Alarms ' etc